# What is proper way to reject contributors for a complex project, based on their skill level, to save on coaching effort?

Tags: problem-contributor

Our team is thinking to call for volunteers to solve an advanced problem in an open source project. The solution for the problem will take collaboration, prototyping and number of pull requests.

And, we are afraid to get contributors, that do not have enough engineering skills (like creating design doc, reviewing it, planning good user experience) and will expect a lot of coaching to deliver the solution, that will create a lot of extra work for maintainers, more than actual work to solve the problem.
While in general we are ok to provide coaching for small tasks, a lot of coaching for project-like tasks seems to be too costly.

Is there a known framework/pattern for selecting/rejecting external contributors for advanced problems in open source projects?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of skills those under-qualified contributors would lack and what kind of coaching you expect would be needed?

Comment: added. Thanks for checking this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most established pattern is called a job interview. I'm aware that's a slightly facetious answer, but the reality of the world is that a large proportion of the "advanced problems" in open source are done by commercial entities who pay people and take the time to vet them first; if you want high quality contributions, it's likely the best way to get them is to pay for them.

You can certainly try the same sort of thing with volunteers - you can ask them to do a "take home" project or something before starting to work with them. But don't expect too many people to take you up on that offer.

Realistically here, it sounds like you may just be best off doing the work yourself.